# .htaccess problem for Drupal

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I decided to ask about this issue, because I found this problem is a common problem for many Drupal designers.

It seems to be a common problem for many drupal designers to face with the Server Error 500 after moving their site to the production server.

There are mainly two lines in the default .htaccess, which are:

```
# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory. 
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory. 
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

So, for some hosts these lines should be removed.

What is your solution, after removing these lines from the .htaccess file? How should the directory listing be prevented?

Comment: I don't understand the 'These two lines according to newer version of Operating Systems or new Servers' config are prevented.' line so I don't understand the whole question.

Comment: maybe that part was misleading. So the problem is that I have to remove the options lines from the .htaccess file.

If I do it, how can I prevent the directory listing?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a Drupal related question, is about Apache .htaccess directives.

Comment: @tunic this is a drupal related issue regarding default webserver configuration options assumed by Drupal core. See my post in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue, see:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1269780 regarding a longterm resolution.

In general it looks like going forward `+FollowSymLinks` should be replaced with `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, but refer to the issue queue item above for a definitive answer.

Typically per host, and definitely with Shared Hosting plans it's up to your webhosts documentation as to what Apache Overrides are allowed by your (system) user account. There is a certain amount of trial and error is seeing if `-Indexes` for example is allowed on your webserver.

This is why when you upgrade Drupal they recommend backups of your projects `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` file as per webhost and project these files are highly likely to be modified.